# Assigning function to Global Variable in Lua

Tags: function, variables, lua, global-variables

This is the sample test code.

```
s="\\command{sample execution}"
u=string.gsub(s,"\\(%b{})",print)
```

It works fine as print is global function. I defined function myprint as follows.

```
myprint = function(x,y)
  return print(x,y)
end
```

Now the command `u=string.gsub(s,"\\(%b{})",myprint)` does not work. This is because the myprint is not global variable as the print is. So basic question that I want to ask is "How to assign function to global variable in Lua?"

Comment: The sample doesn't work. Pattern `"\\(%b{})"` does not match anything in `s`. `"\\%a+(%b{})"` does match. After that everything is just fine with the provided code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to write:

```lua
global_function_1 = function (arg)
    -- body
end
```

or use the syntactic sugar alternative:

```lua
function global_function_2 (arg)
    -- body
end
```

Make sure that the part in which you do that doesn't have a local variable with selected name. For instance **none** of the following functions are global:

```lua
local bar
local function foo (arg)
    local zee
    function arg () end
    zee = function () end
    function bar () end
end
```

Please note that I have totally ignored assigning to table members and ignored existence of `_G` and `_ENV`, and let's leave it this way.

I think that it is worth mentioning that the `string.gsub` (or really any function call) doesn't care whenever the function (or any argument) is local or whatever:

```lua
local str = "abc"
local function fn (x) print(x) end
string.gsub(str, "%a", fn)
```

outputs:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the mistake. I was defining function after string.gsub. It needs to be defined prior to call string.gsub.